# Cannot get "npm install -g" to work on any packages (AppData/Roaming/npm always empty)

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm, gulp, node-modules

Running nodejs on Windows 7 Enterprise at work.

Whenever I install a node_module that needs -g access, from experience I know it's supposed to create a *.bat file in `%AppData$/Roaming/npm`, but for some reason it no longer does that.

For example, I will run `npm install gulp -g`, console looks like it installed correctly, but the files will not be in the AppData folder. And if I try running a gulp command, I get error `sh.exe": gulp: command not found`.

If I run the `npm install gulp -g` command in Console As Administrator, it installs the files into the %AppData% folder of the administrator (instead of the regular user). So if I run the gulp command through my non-administrator user, I still get error `sh.exe": gulp: command not found`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found solution:

(1) Upon running the command: `npm config get prefix`, output is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local`. No idea why it was set to this, as it's not the default.

But I changed it using: `npm config set prefix "$APPDATA\npm"`.

Now when I install a --g module, ie. `npm install gulp -g`, it installs into this desirable directory, no longer throwing `EPERM` and `ENOENT` errors.

(2) Still need to add a `PATH` entry for the npm folder. The command `export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/{YOUR_USERNAME}/AppData/Roaming/npm` works temporarily, but if you close console and open it again, might not be saved (if you are not an administrator).

But you can also use `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/{YOUR_USERNAME}/AppData/Roaming/npm' >> ~/.bash_profile`, which will create a `.bash_profile` file, which is run each time as your console is opened. So from this point, it should automatically add the required `PATH` entry.

Comment: Spent hours looking for a solution that would work. Thanks!

Comment: I wasted hours on this too. Pppppppppppppp. Software development, amaright?

Comment: For exporting the path you may also edit the system environment variable;
path = %appdata%/npm;

Comment: Like Div Tiwari said, edit your system environment variables and then close your command line and reopen it. It will working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. In my case a folder $Appdata/npm/ was getting created which was leading to the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this same issue.

After installing node.js(https://nodejs.org/en/download/) **npm** folder(in **appdata** folder) remain empty.

so, at this stage if you try to build/run angular project(ng build/ng serve), it will give error as:

```
The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

So, for fixing this issue install angular globally in your project with following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Now, there would be data in npm folder(node modules etc.) and ng command will run now.

Comment: After hours of searching this was the only answer which managed to help me out.

Comment: I too spent the last 3 hours fiddling with environment variables, uninstalling and reinstalling node, and everything else.  Nothing worked.   This quickly did.  Thanks.