# Firebase not recognized

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm trying to host my static website on Firebase. But even after installing firebase packages using this cmd- (npm install -g firebase-tools)

when I try to run the command `firebase login then it shows me this error

> {firebase : The term 'firebase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
> a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. }

I have installed many times firebase package but error still there. Sharing snapshot for better illustration.

Any help would be appreciated...thanks in advance. imgage here [link of error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJYF0.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475342/firebase-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progra)

Comment: If you have issues like this, I recommend installing the prebuilt binary of the CLI provided by Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli

Answer (score 5):

- Open your terminal and type `npm ls -g --depth=0`
- Copy the path, mine is `C:\usr\local`
- Close your terminal
- Add the path to `PATH` in user environment variables
- Reopen your terminal
- Type `cd /`
- Type `cd usr\local` (Assume you are you using my path)
- Finally, Type `firebase.cmd login`

If you are still confused, check this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFrfhJXd_EE

Comment: It worked, thanks for the all the answers. I did a silly mistake.