Flutter-Terminal isnt downloading any package. Keeps showing error
My terminal keeps showing these annoying error. Its neither letting me to download any package nor i am able to run any command. This error become so annoying sometimes terminal works, sometimes it doesnt what should i do?
P.S its vscode
It becomes harder for me to run command. 

Read this may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475342/firebase-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progra#:~:text=Make%20sure%20you%20are%20running%20command%20line%20as%20an%20administer.&text=Make%20sure%20you%20run%20the,node%20and%20reinstall%20it%20again.

The question is only links without any explanations.
